# Buttons with line breaks don't display properly on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, button, tkinter

This code works fine in Windows.  On Mac OS X it only shows "Multiple" in the button and everything past the newline gets wiped out.  I'm running Python 2.6.5 on Mac.

```
import Tkinter as tk
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.a_button = tk.Button(master, text="Multiple\nLines\nOf Text")
        self.a_button.pack()

ROOT = tk.Tk()
APP = App(ROOT)
ROOT.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mac native pushbuttons don't let you do that; they have 3 predefined heights for the various control sizes and that's it. Other button styles do support arbitrary dimensions; one option is to use a Tile button instead:

```
    self.a_button = tk.Widget(master, 'ttk::button',
                              dict(text="Multiple\nLines\nOf Text"))
```

Comment: Cool.  Python 2.7/3.1 has "real" Tile support but the above should work just fine as long as you're using a new enough Tk underneath (e.g. OS X 10.6 which comes with Tcl/Tk 8.5.7.)